# Eliminar un fichero dañado en Windows con un monton de metodos fallidos. Formatear unidad corrupta

Tags: formato, msdos

Tengo un fichero, mas concretamente una imagen tomada de la camara, en mi tarjeta sd que esta dañado, me salta el error 0x80070570 al intentar eliminarla. Probe con formatear la tarjeta de un monton de formas, pero, o me da error o me sale que se formatea, pero luego al abrirla tiene todo el contenido aun. Intente formatearla desde el explorador de archivos, desde el administrador de discos, con algunos programas y nada. Tambien trate con cmd y trate de usar el comando CHKDSK, pero nada, al introducir: chkdsk e: /f, me salta un error al final tal que "error al recuperar los archivos perdidos", no se que mas hacer, y la tarjeta en verdad la necesito. Alguna ayuda?

Comment: ¿intentaste mover el archivo a otra carpeta o cambiarle el nombre?

Comment: Es un foro de programacion este, no te mantenimientos de windows, etc.

Comment: Cabe la posibilidad de que lo que esté dañado no sea el archivo sino la memoria SD.

Comment: Cabe la posibilidad de que lo que esté dañado no sea el archivo sino la memoria SD.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando Windows se pone sus moños lo que yo hago es eliminar por completo la particion y volver a crearla (con este metodo vas a perder absolutamente todo lo que tengas en tu memoria) y debes tener mucho cuidado al hacerlo por que si te equivocas puedes borrar otros discos duros en tu computadora

Abre una ventana de linea de comandos en modo administrador (abre el menu windows y escribe `CMD`, después dale click derecho y ejecutar como administrador)

Escribe `diskpart` y presiona enter, si todo salió bien debe aparecerte el prompt como `diskpart>`

Escribe `list disk` y enter, deben aparecer todos los discos conectados a tu computadora incluyendo la memoria, es importante que la identifiques correctamente para que no borres por error otro disco, toma nota del numero que diskpart le asigna

Escribe `select disk n`, donde "n" es el numero del disco que identificaste en el paso anterior, diskpart debe decir `El disco "n" es ahora el disco seleccionado`

Finalmente y si estas seguro escribe `clean`, **UNA VEZ QUE PRESIONES ENTER EL DISCO SERA BORRADO PERMANENTEMENTE**, así que verifica con mucho cuidado que lo que hagas sea correcto

Vuelve a escribir `list disk` y verifica que aparezca un asterisco al lado de tu memoria, esto indica que el disco sigue seleccionado

Para volver a crear una particion escribe `create partition primary` y enter, despues escribe `select partition 1`, enter y finalmente `active`, con esto ya podras leer la memoria de nuevo y podras formatearla de forma convencional

Para salir de diskpart solo escribe `exit` y enter

Espero que te ayude..

Comment: Hola, luego de insertar CLEAN, me da el siguiente error: DiskPart ha encontrado un error: Error de datos (comprobación de redundancia cíclica).
Consulte el registro de eventos del sistema para obtener más información.; el mensaje que muetra el registro es el siguiente: El dispositivo, \Device\Harddisk2\DR8, tiene un bloque defectuoso.

Comment: Tu memoria ya paso a la historia... yo no recomendaria tratar de repararla por que eventualmente vas a terminar perdiendo toda tu informacion, solo tirala a la basura y compra una nueva...